# Как вывести только нужную опцию?

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

Вывожу опции, но нужна одна, конкретная, как это сделать

`{assign var="product_options" value="product_options_'$obj_id'"}
 {$smarty.capture.$product_options nofilter}`

Comment: Еще если кто знает, как использовать для этой опции другой шаблон

Comment: `$smarty.capture.$product_options['YOUR_OPTIONS']` 
`$smarty.capture.$product_options.$SOME_OPTIONS_VARIABLE` 
`$smarty.capture.$product_options.YOUR_OPTIONS` [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно не выводить опции дефолтной капчей. Просто выведите в нужном виде, используя массив $product.product_options

```
{if $product.product_options}
    {foreach from=$product.product_options item=option}
        {if $option.option_id == 123}
            .... здесь вывод опции с ID = 123 ....
        {/if}
    {/foreach} 
{/if}
```